# Different between biceps and triceps?

Tags: muscle, gym, biceps, triceps

According to my knowledge, biceps having 1/3 of arm muscle to build and triceps having 2/3 of arm muscle to build. When I doing exercises in gym, it is bit hard to do triceps rather than biceps. Please explain that issue in depth?

Comment: Triceps exercises --> Cable push down, Ez barskull crashar, D/B seated extension, D/B kick back, Barbell wrist curl.

Comment: It depends on many variables, form, previous exercices, your own physiology, breathing,... What's exactly your routine the day you work triceps? On the other hand, muscles are trained in group. For example, a little improvement of triceps contributes to an improvement training chest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As alluded to, this is an anatomy question.

The term -ceps in muscle anatomy means "heads", or the origin of a muscle. Each muscle has two points of contact (for simplicity), the origin and the insertion. Muscles contract and pull towards the origin, and the insertion moves.

So, biceps means "two heads", and the action of the muscle is to flex the lower arm (Bend it). Triceps means three heads, and the action of the muscle is the extend (straighten) the lower arm.

They should not be much more difficult for one to do than the other, since they are basic motions, which suggests one of two items:

1. Your triceps are much weaker than your biceps, and/or you are using too much weight for your level of training. Lower the amount of weight, and try again. If you still have trouble, that points to #2:
2. Your form is wrong. Get a trainer to look at your form and make sure that you are doing the exercise with correct form.

Also, if you are using a machine, there are recommended ways to set up the machine (rotating points on the machine in line with joints in the body, etc), that may make a difference as well. In that case, see #2.

Answer (score 1):

This is an anatomy question more than anything, but in the context of fitness here is a look at both as a brief overview.

The biceps are a muscle group consisting of two “heads” on the front of the arm, they are responsible for many pulling movements. The triceps are a muscle group consisting of three “heads” on the back of the arm, they are responsible for many pushing movements.

Comment: I need to find it out, why is triceps exercises hard to do?

Comment: @ErandaPeiris - That's a strange question. They're not inherently hard to do. If they're harder than they should be, you may have a problem with your anatomy.

Comment: It is comparison between triceps and biceps exercises.

Comment: It might simply be that your triceps are notably weaker than your biceps. If you neglect to train a muscle group, it won’t grow. If you challenge a muscle group properly however, it will grow. Just check your form (and start with lighter weights if necessary) when doing your triceps training, don’t ego lift. Do your sets to or close to failure, and remember to not skip the eccentric part of the movement. It will take time, but if you’re doing those things (along with proper rest and nutrition) you’ll have a better experience working those triceps out.